# Teamcity fails to fetch files from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity, tfvc

I am very new to the TeamCity and want to learn auto build and deploy applications from online TFS. My project has windows and web apps developed in .NET only.

I have no code on my machine and directly using online TFS as source. 
VCS Root setting works fine and connection gets successful.
In the Build Step, I am using Build as the first step using MSBuild. When I click on RUN  it starts the process and shows the first step as UPDATING SOURCES. In the code checkout directory, it creates only directories and there is no even single source code file though I can see all code files in TFS online. After this step it shows error:

```
Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: 
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\740b9db587af8795\ProjectName.sln
```

`ProjectName.sln` file exists in TFS at `https://ProjectName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$/Main/MainBranch`

[image: See the MSBuild details as below]

[image: Also VCS Root details are as below:]

I am not getting what things I am missing. I googled much about but I wasn't able to get what is missing here. What extra steps I need to do to get this working.

Appreciate your help.

*FI: Teamcity Version 2018.1.3 (build 58658). Teamcity server and build agent are on the same machine: Win 10.*

**Edited:**
Below is screenshot with the RUN process.
[image]

**Teamcity-Activities.log**
[2019-01-07 19:44:23,906]   INFO - s.buildServer.ACTIVITIES.AUDIT - build_type_edit_settings: "MLD / Main {id=Mld_Main, internal id=bt2}" build configuration settings were edited ("version before: 45, version after: 46") by "'admin'(AB) {id=1}" with comment "runners of 'Main' build configuration were updated"

[2019-01-07 19:44:34,460]   INFO - s.buildServer.ACTIVITIES.AUDIT - build_add_to_queue: Build BUILD_PROMOTION{id=52} was added to queue by "'admin'(AB) {id=1}"

[2019-01-07 19:44:34,466]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Build added to queue; Queued build {Build promotion {promotion id=52, configuration={id=Mld_Main, internal id=bt2}, queued}, triggered by "'admin'(AB) {id=1}" (##userId='1' type='user')}

[2019-01-07 19:44:34,539]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Build started; MLD / Main {id=Mld_Main, internal id=bt2} #25 {promotion id=52, agent="Agent-Name" {id=1}, triggered by "'admin'(AB) {id=1}" (##userId='1' type='user'). Started 2019-01-07 19:44:34.514, running}

[2019-01-07 19:55:38,847]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Finished build MLD / Main {id=Mld_Main, internal id=bt2} #25 {promotion id=52, agent="Agent-Name" {id=1}, triggered by "'admin'(AB) {id=1}" (##userId='1' type='user'). Started 2019-01-07 19:44:41.748, finished. Status "FAILURE 'Cannot start build runner; exit code -42 (Step: Build (MSBuild))'"}

**Teamcity-tfs.log**

[2019-01-07 19:42:03,434]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - Starting TFS out of process application

[2019-01-07 19:42:03,439]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - TFS out of process application has been started

[2019-01-07 19:42:08,312]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - Web server started at http://localhost:64729/api/commands

[2019-01-07 19:42:08,312]   INFO - gers.vcs.tfs.TfsTimeoutWatcher - TFS out of process app idle timer has started

[2019-01-07 19:42:25,586]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - TFS java web command has finished: TestConnection $/Main/Feature -s="https://ProjectName.visualstudio.com/" -p="*******", completed in 22.140 second(s)

[2019-01-07 19:43:00,661]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - TFS java web command has finished: GetCurrentVersion $/Main/Feature -s="https://ProjectName.visualstudio.com/" -p="*******", completed in 1.607 second(s)

[2019-01-07 19:44:35,894]   INFO - .vcs.tfs.java.TfsJavaWebRunner - TFS java web command has finished: GetCurrentVersion $/Main/Feature 31529 -s="https://ProjectName.visualstudio.com/" -p="*******", completed in 1.293 second(s)

Comment: Given that the directory is empty, it makes sense that MsBuild can't find the solution file. Let's focus on TeamCity and it failing to get the files instead. Removed [tag:tfs] as you're connecting to [tag:azure-devops]. Adding [tag:tfvc] since that's the source control type you're connecting to.

Comment: Does TeamCity provide any log files of the fetching of files?

Comment: Could you try removing the `/DefaultCollection/` part from the project URI?

Comment: Is the Azure Devops account configured to still use `account.visualstudio.com` or has it been switched to `devops.azure.com/account`?

Comment: Thanks jesse for your comments.

Comment: 1. I checked removing /defaultCollection/ part and still connection gets successful. But still it is not fetching files. It just creates all empty directories only.  2. Didn't see any log file specific for Updating Resources.  3. I can access online code using both account.visualStudio.com and devops.azure.com/accountName. But both ways it still fetches only empty directories. No file getting fetched and so build cannot be done.

Comment: For Information: It fetches all directories inside every project till the all depth. So checkout directory contains around 2K directories as solution is large but no any other file can be seen in the checkout directory.

Comment: It says updating sources to revision... It may be that the files were deleted, but TFVC's cache thinks they're still there. Performing a `force` get version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue issue resolved!
The token generated for the TFVC access was not having sufficient permissions. Changed the access token to have Full Access and it started working and I can see all code files in the checkout directory. 
Thanks jesse for your comments.